# why Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

I'm tryig to save my file in a particular path and also save in mongodb , here i'm using middleware `uploadImg` in `route.js`, but getting and  `Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]`

What is worng here , please help me where i'm wrong here. thanks in advance !!

config/imageUpload.js:-

```
  const multer = require("multer"),
  storage = multer.diskStorage({
     destination: function (req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, 'uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
   }
  })
  const uploadImg = multer({storage: storage}).single('image');
     module.exports = {
       uploadImg: uploadImg,
     }
  return uploadImg;
```

controllers.js:

```
exports.addRoleFields = async (req, res) => {
  const rolesExist = Role.find({ roleType : req.body.roleType })
  if (rolesExist.length > 0){
    res.status(201).send({ message: "Role already exist", statusCode: "201" });
   }
  else {
  const rolesList = new Role ({     
    roleType : req.body.roleType,
    roleImg  : req.file.path,
  });
rolesList
.save(rolesList)   
  .then(data => {
    res.status(200).send({ data, statusCode: "200" });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: err.message || "Some error occurred while creating.",
      statusCode: "500"
    });
  })
 }
}
```

routes.js:

```
module.exports = app => {
 const roles = require("../controllers/roles.js");
 const  uploadImg  = require("../config/imageUpload");
    var router = require("express").Router();
    router.post("/addRole",uploadImg  ,roles.addRoleFields);
    app.use('/api/roles', router);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your config/imageUpload.js you are exporting an object which contains the middleware you created.
You can either:

- Export directly your middleware in imageUpload.js (which is easier)

```
    const multer = require("multer"),
        storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function(req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, 'uploads')
            },
            filename: function(req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
            }
        })
    const uploadImg = multer({
        storage: storage
    }).single('image');
    module.exports = uploadImg
```

- Or, instead, import by destructuring your middleware in your routes.js

```
    module.exports = app => {
        const roles = require("../controllers/roles.js");
        const { uploadImg } = require("../config/imageUpload");
        var router = require("express").Router();
        router.post("/addRole", uploadImg, roles.addRoleFields);
        app.use('/api/roles', router);
    };
```

Comment: i add  `const { uploadImg } = require("../config/imageUpload");` this in `route.js` but still getting same issue